# Is there a way to search inside .doc files?

Tags: php, search, full-text-search, doc

I have around 50,000 ***.doc** files stored on my server(IIS). Now I want to build a search application in php that takes input keywords from user and search content of those files for those keywords. How to do this?

I been googling around for two three days, found few solutions as in **phpword** but that is for **.docx** file only. **catdoc**  is not supported in windows.
So is it possible to search content of the **.doc** file? And if yes, is it possible to perform a search with boolean operators(**and or not** etc.). php file handling functions were of no use either.

If not in PHP any other solution in any programming language will do. I'm in a desperate need to implement this and need a solution. Thank you :)

Comment: You could probably convert the .doc's to .docx.  Heres a blog post on how to batch process them all. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/19/bulk-convert-doc-to-docx.aspx

Comment: @Overachiever This was my first thought when reading this too +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a linux command `grep` and fetch the output with php  - the function you are looking for is `exec()`

```
exec('grep search_term *.doc')
```

Comment: So is grep double-byte charset aware?

Comment: I don't think it will work for Windows... unfortunately, I haven't used windows for a while so I don't know the cmd commands